# ODI Find the usage of a column in interfaces

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I am trying to write a query which shows the relation between source columns, target columns and mappings.

For example I have a source table like T_EMPLOYEE and I have column like JOB_START_DATE,
In ODI, this table and column are being used in some interfaces. These values are being transferred to staging layer and then dimensional layer.
By using query, I want to reach mappings of source column like below:

[image: Mapping]

I tried to write this query but I could not find out the table which holds the mapping information.
Our ODI version is ODI_11.1.1.7.0_GENERIC_130302.2156

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the record, here is the answer I gave somewhere else (with no final feedback) :
Execute this query on your work repository :

```
select I.POP_NAME INTERFACE_NAME, ds.ds_name DATA_SET   
      , s.lschema_name SOURCE_SCHEMA, NVL(S.TABLE_NAME, S.SRC_TAB_ALIAS) SOURCE_TABLE   
      , mt.lschema_name TARGET_SCHEMA, I.TABLE_NAME TARGET_TABLE, c.col_name  TARGET_COLUMN, t.FULL_TEXT MAPPING_CRITERIA   
  from SNP_POP i, SNP_DATA_SET ds, SNP_SOURCE_TAB s, SNP_TXT_HEADER t, SNP_POP_MAPPING m, SNP_POP_COL c, SNP_TABLE trg, snp_model mt   
  where I.I_POP = DS.I_POP  (+)   
    and DS.I_DATA_SET = S.I_DATA_SET (+)   
    and T.I_TXT (+) = M.I_TXT_MAP   
    and M.I_POP_COL (+) = C.I_POP_COL  
    and M.I_DATA_SET = DS.I_DATA_SET (+)  
    and C.I_POP (+) = I.I_POP   
    and I.i_table = trg.i_table (+)   
    and trg.i_mod = mt.i_mod (+);
```

Comment: Could you give an example so I can try to figure out why and improve the query? Is there anything special with these mappings? Like no reference of  a source columns, or execution on the target?